# Proto to describe JSON structure which has a list of items with two possible type

Tags: json, schema, protocol-buffers

I have a JSON-structured data that contains list. Every list item is either a simple string of an object.

```
{
  "oneOfArray": [
    "str1",
    "str2",
    {"SomeStruct": "value3"},
    "str4",
    {"SomeStruct": "value5"}
  ]
}
```

I want to create a proto describing this structure. (The internal API creation document mandates using Protobuf and GRPC for all APIs.)

How can I describe such a schema in protobuf? (It's pretty easy to describe in JsonSchema, but I'm struggling with proto)

I want `google.protobuf.json_format.Parse` to be able to deserialize the JSON data to a protobuf message of the generated type.